# Php code runs twice from url request

Tags: php, phpmailer

My php code for a website I am designing is running twice. This is day three of the bug and I am running out of options.

I have used the error log to confirm that the script is running twice.

```
[25-Sep-2013 11:18:27] PHP Notice:  renaming. should not see this twice... in /home3/projedc4/public_html/formhandler.php on line 149
[25-Sep-2013 11:18:29] PHP Notice:  renaming. should not see this twice... in /home3/projedc4/public_html/formhandler.php on line 149
[25-Sep-2013 11:18:29] PHP Warning:  rename(/home3/projedc4/public_html/tmparea/3170936.mp3,/home3/projedc4/public_html/uploads/3170936.mp3) [<a href='function.rename'>function.rename</a>]: No such file or directory in /home3/projedc4/public_html/formhandler.php on line 15
```

(Note: I used to think it was a rename issue, hence the renaming error I generated. I later saw it was running twice so I added the extra bit about not seeing it twice. Also, the line references are wrong because I shortened up the code and removed classified information.)

I have tested other chunks of the script on the server and they do not run twice (e.x. The emailer). The strange thing is that it is not a form submission or even a link destination. I am requesting straight from the url with no html involved.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
#grab variables
if (($_COOKIE["braceletreg"]) != "") {
    $beattype = "bracelet";
} 
if (($_COOKIE["neckreg1"]) != "") {
    $beattype = "regular necklace clamp";
} 
if (($_COOKIE["neckreg2"]) != "") {
    $beattype = "regular necklace clamp";
} 
if (($_COOKIE["neckjack"]) != "") {
    $beattype = "Headphone jack necklace";
} 
if (($_COOKIE["fwhite"]) != "") {
    $color = "White";
} 
if (($_COOKIE["fblack"]) != "") {
    $color = "black";
} 
if (($_COOKIE["fgreen"]) != "") {
    $color = "green";
} 
if (($_COOKIE["forange"]) != "") {
    $color = "orange";
} 
if (($_COOKIE["stringtype"]) != "") {
    $stringcolor = "Black string";
} 
if (($_COOKIE["stringtype2"]) != "") {
    $stringcolor = "White string";
}
$name = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['fname']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['femail']);
$phone = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['fphone']);
$adress = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['fadress']);
$customtext = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['fcustomtext']);
$number= $_COOKIE['ponum'];

#create dynamic page
function createpage($number,$extention) {
$fh = fopen("uploads/".$number.".html", 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh,$number.$extention);
fclose($fh);
echo "file saved";
}

#email content and confirm to user.
function emailsystem($number,$name,$color,$beattype,$phone,$adress,$customtext,$email,$stringcolor,$extention){
include_once('class_phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server
    $mail->From = "order@form.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Your Name";
    $mail->AddAddress("email@thing.com", "Their Name");
    $mail->AddAttachment("uploads/".$number.".".$extention);
    $mail->AddReplyTo("me@mydomain.com", "me");

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = "PHPmailer example".$number;
    $mail->Body = "Name: " . $name . "<br>
    color: " . $color . "<br>
    string color: " . $stringcolor . "<br>
    type: " . $beattype . "<br>
    phone: " . $phone . "<br>
    Address: " . $adress . "<br>
    Customtext: " . $customtext . "<br>
    email: " . $email . "<br>
    PO Number".$number."<br>";

    if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    } else {
        exit;
    }
}
#identify and Move file and create
echo $number."<br>";
if (file_exists("tmparea/" . $number.".mp3") == true) {
    $extention = "mp3";
} else if (file_exists("tmparea/" . $newname.".wav") == true) {
    $extention = "wav";
} else{
    echo "cant get file<br>";
    $extention = "mp3";
}
echo $number.$extention." This is the extention<br>";
trigger_error("renaming. should not see this twice...");
rename('/home3/projedc4/public_html/tmparea/'.$number.'.'.$extention, '/home3/projedc4/public_html/uploads/'.$number.'.'.$extention);
createpage($number,$extention);
emailsystem($number,$name,$color,$beattype,$phone,$adress,$customtext,$email,$stringcolor,$extention);
?>
```

(I know there are spelling errors and such in my code. That is okay. I know they are there and will clean up the code later. Right now I just need to know why its running twice and any other coding related advice.)

What I believe is going on is that the program is running fine the first time and emailing me. then it runs again, giving me the rename error (this is confirmed with two emails in my inbox with the same attachment.) and I have no idea why. Any help would be much appreciated...

**EDIT**

I was doing some testing and it turns out that when the email is sent, the script runs twice. (I figured this out by commenting out the `$mail->Sent()`). Does anyone know how to fix this? If I don't get an answer soon, I think I will just switch to file creation and another means of notification.

**EDITED EDIT**

I have decided to make my own system that doesn't rely on email. It will be faster, easier and more user friendly than email, but I would still like to see this answered. So if anyone has any more ideas, please let me know.

Comment: the error is likely to be elsewhere in your application

Comment: Please explain more. As far as I am concerned, this is all that is running (due to the fact that it is a url request E.X. typing in the url bar "www.website.com/test.php") I have left nothing out that would be of importance. (I only left out fwrite operations and some comments.)

Comment: (1) check you apache access log, if there's a double entry in there as well, you have your problem, and fix it on that side (2) if there's only one entry in the access log for this request, but you still get double, include a backtrace from `debug_backtrace()` in your `trigger_error()` to find out where the double / repeat call originates in your code.

Comment: What it looks like in the code is that the customer can only order one item at a time. What if they wanted the bracelet and the headphone jack necklace?

Comment: @GaryHayes Right, I plan on adding more as time goes on. I am on a schedule though and need to get SOMETHING up and running.

Wrikken: I could not find the apache access log. I am running on a justhost page and I am not sure where they keep it. I did debug_backtrace() and it returned the value array(0){}. I am not sure why or what that means...

Comment: @JakeMoz That's cool, just wanted to make sure you're aware of it before you code too much and have to change it all later on. I have a site that uses a cookie based shopping cart too, but my newer sites use a temp table in a database to hold shopping cart info so the user can move from device to device and still have access to their cart. The cons of doing that is they have to log in so the site knows who's cart to store and grab, whereas cookies dont require a log in to get their cart info. So use cookies if not logged in, then if they do log in, copy the cookie info to the temp table.